# Is there a way I can make this less messy?

Tags: java, eclipse, project

So I was given hangman as a project to do and I am supposed to replace all the letters with underscores.  My code currently looks like this:

```
public static void prompt(){
    BufferedReader delta = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
//Prompts one user for puzzle
    //must have at least one word
    //no more than eight words
    //cannot be an empty string
    //puzzle
            //letters are made as underscores
            // spaces and special characters are displayed as normal
    boolean valid = false;
    while(!valid){
    System.out.println("Player 1, please enter a word or a phrase.");
    System.out.println("Note: There cannot be more than eight words.");
    try{
    String input = delta.readLine();
    if(input.isEmpty()){
        valid = false;
        System.out.println("Your answer is invalid");
    }else{
        valid = true;
    }
    input = input.replaceAll("a", "_");
    input = input.replaceAll("b", "_");
    input = input.replaceAll("c", "_");
    input = input.replaceAll("d", "_");
    input = input.replaceAll("e", "_");
    input = input.replaceAll("f", "_");
    input = input.replaceAll("g", "_");
    input = input.replaceAll("h", "_");
    input = input.replaceAll("i", "_");
    input = input.replaceAll("j", "_");
    input = input.replaceAll("k", "_");
    input = input.replaceAll("l", "_");
    input = input.replaceAll("m", "_");
    input = input.replaceAll("n", "_");
    input = input.replaceAll("o", "_");
    input = input.replaceAll("p", "_");
    input = input.replaceAll("q", "_");
    input = input.replaceAll("r", "_");
    input = input.replaceAll("s", "_");
    input = input.replaceAll("t", "_");
    input = input.replaceAll("u", "_");
    input = input.replaceAll("v", "_");
    input = input.replaceAll("w", "_");
    input = input.replaceAll("x", "_");
    input = input.replaceAll("y", "_");
    input = input.replaceAll("z", "_");

    input = input.replaceAll("A", "_");
    input = input.replaceAll("B", "_");
    input = input.replaceAll("C", "_");
    input = input.replaceAll("D", "_");
    input = input.replaceAll("E", "_");
    input = input.replaceAll("F", "_");
    input = input.replaceAll("G", "_");
    input = input.replaceAll("H", "_");
    input = input.replaceAll("I", "_");
    input = input.replaceAll("J", "_");
    input = input.replaceAll("K", "_");
    input = input.replaceAll("L", "_");
    input = input.replaceAll("M", "_");
    input = input.replaceAll("N", "_");
    input = input.replaceAll("O", "_");
    input = input.replaceAll("P", "_");
    input = input.replaceAll("Q", "_");
    input = input.replaceAll("R", "_");
    input = input.replaceAll("S", "_");
    input = input.replaceAll("T", "_");
    input = input.replaceAll("U", "_");
    input = input.replaceAll("V", "_");
    input = input.replaceAll("W", "_");
    input = input.replaceAll("X", "_");
    input = input.replaceAll("Y", "_");
    input = input.replaceAll("Z", "_");

    System.out.println(input);

    }catch(IOException IOE){

    }
```

Is there any way I could clean this up so that I'm not repeating myself?

Comment: Research about patterns in Java and you'll find what you need: [Reference - What does this regex mean?](//stackoverflow.com/q/22937618)

Comment: Note: if you are trying to replace a string with another string (i.e. you don't need regular expressions), use `String.replace` rather than `String.replaceAll`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regular expression to replace all of those characters in one call:

```
input.replaceAll("[a-zA-Z]","_");
```

This will match on any character that is a lower or upper case letter and replace it with an underscore. You can learn more about regular expressions in Java [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/).